# FOR loop in object/array

Tags: python

I'm creating an application using python. I make a HTTP request and get a following  result:

```
{
    "companies": {
        "company": [
            {
                "createDt": "2014-01-18T00:00:00+01:00",
                "dbNazev": "sveatlo_s_r_o_",
                "id": "1",
                "licenseGroup": "null",
                "nazev": "Sveatlo s.r.o.",
                "show": "true",
                "stavEnum": "ESTABLISHED",
                "watchingChanges": "false"
            },
            {
                "createDt": "2014-01-20T00:00:00+01:00",
                "dbNazev": "hajocka",
                "id": "2",
                "licenseGroup": "null",
                "nazev": "HÃ¡joÄka",
                "show": "true",
                "stavEnum": "ESTABLISHED",
                "watchingChanges": "false"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Then I'm processing the data in a for loop. the problem is that the response may also look like this:

```
{
    "companies": {
        "company": {
            "createDt": "2014-01-18T00:00:00+01:00",
            "dbNazev": "sveatlo_s_r_o_",
            "id": "1",
            "licenseGroup": "null",
            "nazev": "Sveatlo s.r.o.",
            "show": "true",
            "stavEnum": "ESTABLISHED",
            "watchingChanges": "false"
        }
    }
}
```

Currently I'm checking if it is an array or not after each request like this, but I feel it's not the best way to do this. Could anybody please help me to find a better solution?

Thanks for any answer.

edit: I cannot change the server's response

Comment: Would be helpful to post the code with which you access the json.

Comment: are you using the json module?

Comment: I'm using ujson, but the JSON-string to python object is made by requests module build-in functionality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normalize the information you're parsing. This will prevent you having to repeat yourself:

Say you have data that could either look like this:

```
some_json_data = {"companies": {"foo": 1}}
```

or like this:

```
some_json_data = {"companies": [{"foo": 1}]}
```

So when you parse the json data, do this:

```
i_expect_an_array = some_json_data['companies']
if not isinstance(i_expect_an_array, list):
    i_expect_an_array = (i_expect_an_array,)

# Now, you can process the data as you normally would
```

No need for two separate blocks of similar looking code.

Comment: Its better tu use tuple instead of list

Comment: Tuple is faster than list. Also server response is not changeable thing, so its better logic to don't allow to change it.

Comment: Considering that any tiny speed improvements from using a `tuple` will be subsumed by the time it takes to convert the input `list` to a `tuple`, I don't think it makes much of a difference.

Comment: You don't need to convert list to tuple, just dict to tuple!

Comment: @Lukas: Touché, I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: If you need something like list or tuple and you have for example dict, its better to convert dict to tuple, because tuple is faster than list.

Comment: The speed benefits of a tuple, if any, are completely overshadowed by the maintainability benefits of always having a list there. Who knows whether some developer will later try to modify the list in-place, thinking you've normalized the representation?

Answer (score 2):

Convert not list to list or tuple and then loop:

```
def make_list(item):
    if not isinstance(item, (list, tuple)):
        return [item]
    return list(item)

for company in make_list(data['companies']['company']):
    process_company(company)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `make_list` be named `make_tuple`?